# Print a variable in theme file from drupal module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

This is code of vegas.module file. it is used to load images from specific folder.

```
   function vegas_init() {
  // Load all the images to be added to Vegas.
  $backgrounds = array();
  $fade = variable_get('vegas_fade', 0);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $fid = variable_get('vegas_images_' . $i, '');
    if (!empty($fid)) {
      $image = file_load($fid);
      if ($image) {
        $background = array(
          'src' => file_create_url($image->uri),
        );
        if (!empty($fade)) {
          $background['fade'] = intval($fade);
        }
        $backgrounds[] = $background;
      }
    }
  }
```

I print it in .module file. It gives the expected result.

```
print_r($backgrounds);
```

If i print it in my theme's page.tpl.php it doesn't return any values. Is there any way to load module's variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print this varibale in page.tpl.php - use hook_preprocess_page

function custom_preprocess_page(&$variables), not node.

Comment: Why should i place that function inside template.php

Comment: If some developer after you will change your template files - he will see all changes of template variables in one file and he will not search this changes in modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hook_preprocess_page to add variables to page template or hook_preprocess_node to add variable to node template.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) { //can be MYTHEME_preprocess_node and locate in template.php
  // Load all the images to be added to Vegas.
  $backgrounds = array();
  $fade = variable_get('vegas_fade', 0);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $fid = variable_get('vegas_images_' . $i, '');
    if (!empty($fid)) {
      $image = file_load($fid);
      if ($image) {
        $background = array(
          'src' => file_create_url($image->uri),
        );
        if (!empty($fade)) {
          $background['fade'] = intval($fade);
        }
        $variables['backgrounds'][] = $background;
      }
    }
  }
```

Try this code and in yoot node.tpl.php will be avaliable $backgrounds array.

I think more correctly to put this code to template.php in your theme. It will be easiest to view how chaged node variables

Answer (score 0):

My theme name is custom. Here's what i have pasted into template.php file

```
function custom_preprocess_node(&$variables) { //can be MYTHEME_preprocess_node and locate in template.php
  // Load all the images to be added to Vegas.
  $backgrounds = array();
  $fade = variable_get('vegas_fade', 0);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $fid = variable_get('vegas_images_' . $i, '');
    if (!empty($fid)) {
      $image = file_load($fid);
      if ($image) {
        $background = array(
          'src' => file_create_url($image->uri),
        );
        if (!empty($fade)) {
          $background['fade'] = intval($fade);
        }
        $variables['backgrounds'][] = $background;
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

and print it page.tpl.php file

```
print_r($backgrounds);
```